# Building a ranking list in Python: how to assign scores to contestants?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

*(I posted this on the wrong section of Stackexchange before, sorry)*

I'm working on a assignment which is way above my head. I've tried for days on end figuring out how to do this, but I just can't get it right... 
I have to make a ranking list in which I can enter a user, alter the users score, register if he/she payed and display all users in sequence of who has the most score.

The first part I got to work with CSV, I've put only the basic part in here to save space. The menu and import csv have been done: (I had to translate a lot from my native language, sorry if there is a mistake, I know it's a bad habit).

```
more = True
while more:
    print("-" * 40)
    firstname = raw_input("What is the first name of the user?: ")
    with open("user.txt", "a") as scoreFile:
        scoreWrite = csv.writer(scoreFile)
        scoreWrite.writerow([firstname, "0", "no"])
    scoreFile.close()
    mr_dnr = raw_input("Need to enter more people? If so, enter 'yes' \n")
    more = mr_dnr in "yes \n"
```

This way I can enter the name. Now I need a second part (other option in the menu of course) to:

1. let the user enter the name of the person
2. after that enter the (new) score of that person.

So it needs to alter the second value in any entry in the csv file ("0") to something the user enters without erasing the name already in the csv file.

Is this even possible? A kind user suggested using SQlite3, but this basic CSV stuff is already stretching it far over my capabilities...

Comment: how about using dictionary, then with pandas package, convert the dict into dataframe and finally generate the CSV files? Altering the CSV all the times when the application runs is not a good solution, better get the CSV into pandas dataframe, alter the value in dataframe, and finally when the application stops, rewrite the CSV

Comment: @Po Thanks for your comment :) The problem is that we are not 'allowed' to use things that do not already exist in Python itself.

Comment: well you cant update the CSV in the middle, its just like you need to overwrite all the CSV.
if it is okay, you can create a function to read the csv into dict {user:score}, update the dict and convert it back to csv and overwrite the old csv

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is right that SQlite3 would be a much better approach to this. If this is stretching your knowledge too far, I suggest having a directory called users and having one file per user. Use JSON (or pickle) to write the user information and overwrite the entire file each time you need to update it.

Comment: Thanks, I have made this assignment before and got a 4/10 using a dictionary. With that attempt I inputted the name and score at once without the ability to change that value. If there is a way to alter a value in a dictionary (so [name, score], creating a user: [Hank, 0], and then enter a score for any registered used e.g. 10 points [Hank, 10]). That would solve my problem for the most part.

Comment: I'm really confused at what you are saying here. Dictionaries are mutable. You can always update values in a dictionary.